# Are there any situations in physics when uniform convergence shouldn't be ignored?

Tags: mathematical-physics

A uniformly convergent series $k_n(x)$ can be multiplied or differentiated term-by-term:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int k_n dx \equiv \int \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} k_n dx$ and

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} k_n(x) dx \equiv \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} k_n(x) dx$.

To be on the safe side, I always try and justify that the series satisfies the Weierstrass' M-test but all physiscists I know always summarily swap like they don't know it could in theory cause issues.

Am I exaggerating or are there in fact situations in physics when uniform convergence is relevant?

Comment: I believe naive derivations of the Dirac delta function are an example. Mathematically correct usage uses distributions. See [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). On second thought. this is probably an example of a different mathematical issue that physicists ignore.

Comment: @mmesser314  I'm very frustrated whenever I see someone just swap these operators. I tried pointing it out but it always just leads to a lot of confusion: "What does convergent mean?" or "We're physicists first, we're not mathematicians". I think it's negligent not to study basic abstract maths. Most people I know don't understand where integrals come from. They just look them up but have never derived them.

Comment: I have written about this difference in viewpoint several times. Both mathematicians and physicists have valid reasons for their choices. See [this anwer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/553749/37364). And [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/158902/37364). And [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/355760/37364).

Comment: Yes. There are many physics papers where it is important. E.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9811257 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01357

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For many of the well studied ODEs and PDEs, there are powerful uniqueness results about solutions. It's much simpler to *assume* the manipulations are valid, and *then* justify the manipulations by demonstrating the resulting solution satisfies the differential equation and boundary conditions. If it does- great! If not, we need to think more carefully about the manipulations.

I'd like to give a slightly bigger picture view regarding how this comes about. The 'issues' you ask about are frequent, and very real, but (it is hoped) not insuperable. [Many problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) come down to an integral of the form

$$\tag{1}
I(a)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \exp(-x^2+a P(x))
$$

For some given function $P(x)$, often a polynomial. For essentially every nontrivial choice of $P$, the integral cannot be done in closed form. We can try *something* or give up. One thing to try is expanding the second exponential

$$\tag{2}
I(a)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \  e^{-x^2}\left[1+aP+\frac{(aP)^2}{2}+\cdots \right]
$$

If we commute the summation past the integral, the problem is simple!

$$\tag{3}
I(a)=\sum\limits_n\frac{a^n}{n!}\int dx \ e^{-x^2}P(x)^n
$$

Each polynomial times Gaussian may be integrated easily. We're left with a series solution

$$\tag{4}
I(a)=\sum\limits_n C_na^n
$$

And (4) is pretty much guaranteed to diverge. This is because it was not valid to commute the sum and integral to get from (2) to (3) if $a=0$ is a singular point. Example: $P(x)=x^4$, then (1) converges only for $a \leq 0$ and diverges for $a>0$. In a different problem, we might have started with a differential equation, tried a perturbation series solution, and would end up with something very similar to (4). I point this out because: this type procedure is one of the few ways to 'break into' hard problems, and is ubiquitous in physics.

The surprising thing is that (4) is *still useful*. It may be an [asymptotic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) and there are [methods](http://www.nhn.ou.edu/%7Emilton/p5013/chap8.pdf) to 'sum' the divergent series and get a finite result. It is quite difficult to prove things *in generality* about these techniques, but for a class of problems including those in non-relativistic quantum mechanics, the analog of (4) can be shown rigorously to make sense$^\dagger$. They have also been [quite good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_magnetic_dipole_moment) agreements with experiment, even when the summation cannot be rigorously justified.

Generally, in physics we *expect* the answers to have a certain 'regularity' or 'niceness'. So even if a manipulation is not fully justified for *arbitrary functions*, it may be justified for a certain class of nice-enough functions. Fortunately these are the ones we are often interested in.

$\dagger$ This was mentioned in one of Carl Bender's [lectures](https://pirsa.org/C11025). I'd also highly recommend his book *Advanced mathematical methods* if any of this sounds interesting.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the fact that 'solving' a problem by giving a divergent (but asymptotic) series is actually often good enough. I wonder if the OP objects to Stirling's formula?

Comment: @jacob1729 Actually, *as I clicked post*, I wondered if I should have discussed Stirling's approximation!